# Limit of a series with a lot of dependencies

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $n \rightarrow \infty$ and consider

$$\sum_{x=\lfloor \log^6(n)\rfloor}^{\lceil \frac{n}{\log^2(n)}\rceil} \left(\frac{n}{\log^2(n) x} e^{-\frac{\log^{16}(n)}{n}}\right)^x$$

Do we know anything about the convergence of this sum? In particular, does it maybe go to 0?

Thank you very much for any hints!

Comment: The summation notation only really makes sense when the bounds are integers.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. Let the bounds be floored and ceiled, I will adapt this in the question.

Comment: Technically true, but throw in some floors and ceiling in the mix -- it won't change the convergence. @Gaffney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lower bound your sum $S_n$ by its first term,
$$
S_n \geq \left( \frac{n}{\log^8 n} e^{-\frac{\log^{16} n}{n}} \right)^{\log^6 n}
 = e^{\log^7 n - 8\log^6 n \cdot \log\log n - \frac{\log^{22} n}{n}} = e^{\log^7 n + o(\log^7 n)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$

Comment: Wow, such an easy and nice solution. Thank you very much for that!